# What are the possible mission outcomes in the singleplayer campaign?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Over the course of the campaign I've had some rousing successes and abject failures. I'm interested in knowing what the possible outcomes of each mission are and a brief explanation how to achieve them (e.g. run faster in Karma to get result x).

Comment: I think the people who are downvoting/voting to close aren't very familiar with the game, there are only 10 missions and they seem to have at most 2 opportunities to change the outcome, while most only have 1 or none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found this on [Call of Duty Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty_Wiki). I think it covers every single possible outcome for the game (here's the [direct link](http://images.wikia.com/callofduty/images/2/25/Choices_in_Black_Ops_II.png) to the image).

[image: Possible BO2 outcomes]

Comment: Yup, I'm glad they did all the work for us, :p